# Knight walk backtracking solution issue

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I have a doubt on the backtracking solution I wrote for below problem:

```
Given a square chessboard of N x N size, the position of Knight and the position of a target are given. We need to find out the minimum steps a Knight will take to reach the target position
```

My back tracking solution is :

```
    #knight walk problem
 #knight walk problem
#cx---crnt x value
#cy---crnt y value
#Dx---destintion X value
#Dy----destintion Y value
#count---count of steps


def kingnight(Cx,Cy,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps):
  if Cx==Dx and Cy==Dy:
    outboard[Cx][Cy]=1
    return steps
  if Cx<0 or Cy<0 or Cx>=len(outboard) or Cy>=len(outboard) or outboard[Cx][Cy]==1:
    return float('inf')
  outboard[Cx][Cy]=1
  min1=kingnight(Cx+2,Cy-1,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps+1)
  min2=kingnight(Cx+2,Cy+1,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps+1)
  min3=kingnight(Cx-2,Cy+1,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps+1)
  min4=kingnight(Cx-2,Cy-1,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps+1)
  min5=kingnight(Cx+1,Cy+2,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps+1)
  min6=kingnight(Cx+1,Cy-2,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps+1)
  min7=kingnight(Cx-1,Cy+2,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps+1)
  min8=kingnight(Cx-1,Cy-2,Dx,Dy,outboard,steps+1)
  crntmin=min(min1,min2,min3,min4,min5,min6,min7,min8)
  outboard[Cx][Cy]=0 #backtracking
  return crntmin
```

When I call the function:

```
n=4
board=[[0 for _ in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
kingnight(1,1,0,0,board,0)
```

It shows the expected output. But when I call with the below:

```
n=6
board=[[0 for _ in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
kingnight(2,3,5,5,board,0)
```

It should return 3 but is an infinite loop.

**Where I am wrong?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your algorithm is looking for *every* possible path that the knight can take from the starting position. On larger boards this number of paths grows exponentially. Your loop is not infinite; it just needs to check too many paths.

If we simplify a bit and assume that the knight on a 6x6 board can take on average 4 moves, and that paths are on average 20 steps long, then we have 4<sup>20</sup> paths, i.e. 1e+12 paths. This is an underestimation.

### How to solve

This brute force algorithm is not good enough.

Use a breadth-first search instead of a depth-first search and log on each visited board cell the (shortest) distance from the source (which also serves as a visited-marker). Unvisited fields should be initialised with -1. The source will get 0, ...etc.

That will be the main improvement you need. You can also apply some heuristics, and turn it into an A* algorithm, where the estimated steps to the target should be an underestimation, so for instance the taxicab distance divided by 3.

### Implementation

I went for an implementation where you don't pass the board to the function, but just `n`, and the function returns a path of coordinates.

The function will then create its board locally and fill it during the breadth-first with values that represent the position where the knight came from on its optimal path (to that square).

Here is the code:

```
def kingnight(cx,cy,dx,dy,n):
    board=[[0 for _ in range(n)] for i in range(n)]
    q = [(cx, cy)]
    board[cx][cy] = (-1, -1)
    while q:
        frontier = []
        for cx, cy in q:
            for mx, my in ((-2,-1),(-1,-2),(1,-2),(2,-1),(1,2),(2,1),(-2,1),(-1,2)):
                tx = cx + mx
                ty = cy + my
                if 0 <= tx < n and 0 <= ty < n and not board[tx][ty]:
                    board[tx][ty] = (cx, cy)
                    if tx == dx and ty == dy:
                        # build path
                        path = []
                        while tx >= 0:
                            path.append((tx, ty))
                            tx, ty = board[tx][ty]
                        return path[::-1]
                    frontier.append((tx, ty))
        q = frontier
    return  # Not possible

# Demo
n=6
print(kingnight(2,3,5,5,n))
```